# Treeview nodes (Windows Forms) are drawn on the first line before fully initializing the complete Treeview when using DrawMode: OwnerDrawText

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, rendering

I'm using a treeview (Windows Forms) with DrawMode: TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawText. But I'm having a problem with rendering the content. Before the treeview is fully initialized the treeview nodes are drawn on the first line of the treeview like this:

[image]

After the treeviews is fully initialized everything is drawn fine:

[image]

But I don't want to see the render pre-initialization that you see in the first screenshot.
Sometimes when the treeview loads very fast this pre-initialization is not visible.
It might have something to do with that the OwnerDrawText mode has rather slow rendering?

The code I use for the DrawTreeNodeEventsArgs event is as followed:

```
private void myTreeView_DrawNode(
object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
    //Draw the background and node text for a selected node.
    if ((e.State & TreeNodeStates.Selected) != 0)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.AliceBlue, NodeBounds(e.Node));
    }
    else
    {
        if (e.Node.Name != null)
        {
            int color;
            bool isValidInt = int.TryParse(e.Node.Name.ToString(), out color);

            if (isValidInt)
            {
                Brush colorBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(color));
                //e.Graphics.FillRectangle(colorBrush, new Rectangle(e.Bounds.Right + 2, e.Bounds.Top, 10, 10));

                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(colorBrush, new Rectangle(e.Bounds.Left + 2, e.Bounds.Top + 2, 10, 10));

                e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Node.Text.ToString(), tagFont,
                Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.Left + 12, e.Bounds.Top);

            }
            else
            {
                e.DrawDefault = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if ((e.State & TreeNodeStates.Focused) != 0)
    {
        //e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.AliceBlue, NodeBounds(e.Node));

        //using (Pen focusPen = new Pen(Color.Black))
        //{
        //    focusPen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dot;
        //    Rectangle focusBounds = NodeBounds(e.Node);
        //    focusBounds.Size = new Size(focusBounds.Width - 1,
        //    focusBounds.Height - 1);
        //    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(focusPen, focusBounds);
        //}
    }
}
```

Does anybody know how to prevent this pre-initialization rendering effect seen in the first screenshot? Ok thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try [suspendlayout and resume layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout?view=windowsdesktop-8.0)

Comment: Thank you! Should the SuspendLayout method be called at the first line of the myTreeView_DrawNode event and the ResumeLayout method be called at the last line of this event? Where should this normally be applied in this case?

Comment: No, not n the DrawNode event! This is called for each node.. Call it before you update the data and resume afterwards. Also make sure to keep the calls paired.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
private bool isExpandingOrCollapsing = false;

    protected override void OnBeforeExpand(TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        isExpandingOrCollapsing = true;

        this.BeginUpdate();
        base.OnBeforeExpand(e);
    }

    protected override void OnAfterExpand(TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        isExpandingOrCollapsing = false;

        base.OnAfterExpand(e);
        this.EndUpdate();
    }

    protected override void OnAfterCollapse(TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnAfterCollapse(e);
        this.EndUpdate();
    }
```

and then in your drawing sub, check the isExpandingOrCollapsing value:

```
    protected override void OnDrawNode(DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
        //do not draw if not visible
        if (e.Node.IsVisible == false) return;

        // do not draw if extanding or collapsing
        if (isExpandingOrCollapsing) return;
 ...}
```

Comment: Thank you! I found out I missed this line of code in the myTreeView_DrawNode event:  if (e.Node.IsVisible == false) return; . If I add this to the beginning of the myTreeView_DrawNode event code the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I found out I missed this line of code in the myTreeView_DrawNode event:

```
if (e.Node.IsVisible == false) return;
```

If I add this to the beginning of the myTreeView_DrawNode event code the problem is solved.

```
private void myTreeView_DrawNode(
object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Node.IsVisible == false) return;

    //Draw the background and node text for a selected node.
    if ((e.State & TreeNodeStates.Selected) != 0)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.AliceBlue, NodeBounds(e.Node));
    }
    else
    {
        if (e.Node.Name != null)
        {
            int color;
            bool isValidInt = int.TryParse(e.Node.Name.ToString(), out color);

            if (isValidInt)
            {
                Brush colorBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(color));
                //e.Graphics.FillRectangle(colorBrush, new Rectangle(e.Bounds.Right + 2, e.Bounds.Top, 10, 10));

                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(colorBrush, new Rectangle(e.Bounds.Left + 2, e.Bounds.Top + 2, 10, 10));

                e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Node.Text.ToString(), tagFont,
                Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.Left + 12, e.Bounds.Top);

            }
            else
            {
                e.DrawDefault = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if ((e.State & TreeNodeStates.Focused) != 0)
    {
        //e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.AliceBlue, NodeBounds(e.Node));

        //using (Pen focusPen = new Pen(Color.Black))
        //{
        //    focusPen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dot;
        //    Rectangle focusBounds = NodeBounds(e.Node);
        //    focusBounds.Size = new Size(focusBounds.Width - 1,
        //    focusBounds.Height - 1);
        //    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(focusPen, focusBounds);
        //}
    }
}
```

Works like a charm this way.